# rpm upgrade | add new files without removing the old ones

Tags: linux, rpm

I develop a software which is distributed and installed via rpm. During install, I copy some binaries to a destination directory.

When performing rpm upgrade, I'd like the old binaries **not to be deleted**, and that the new ones will be added as is.

Is there an rpm built-in way to do so? I'd really like to avoid scripting in order to resolve that...

**EDIT:**

The above binaries were listed in `@files` section.

Answer (score 0):

If you are manually copying the files to some directory (in `%post` for example) then yum/rpm doesn't know anything about them and can't remove them.

If you have them listed in the `%files` section (i.e. copying them to the right place under buildroot during `%install) then no, I do not believe you can have rpm leave files not listed by the new package on the system after upgrading to a newer version of the package which does not contain those files.

It *might* be possible to play with marking them as `%config` files and then "modifying" them so that rpm won't remove them but it might still rename them and I don't know if this will actually work.